# Source that the prosperity of a community is based on the merits of the founders of the community

Tags: sources-mekorot, tzibur-community

A Devar Torah I was reading stated that it is well known that the prosperity and success of a community is based on the merit of the people who founded that community. This is a fascinating concept. What is the source of that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never mind, I found it. Its the [Rav on Avos 2:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.2.2?lang=bi&p2=Bartenura_on_Pirkei_Avot.2.2.5&lang2=bi)

> שזכות אבותם מסיעתן. שזכות אבותן של צבור וצדקתן העומדת לעד היא המסיעת אל העוסקין עמהן להוציא לאור צדקן, ולא מצד טוב השתדלותן של העוסקים:
>   "for the merit of their ancestors sustains them": For the merit and righteousness (tsidkatan) of the ancestors of the community - which stands forever - sustains those that work with them, to bring their righteousness to the fore. And it is not from the angle of the efforts of those that work [for the community].